# C# UWP Understanding StoreAppLicense IsTrial and ExpirationDate

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, trial

I have a UWP app that I have had on the Windows Store for over a year. Until recently, I never had it configured as a trial. The app was free forever, but the app had limited capability unless the user bought a durable add-on. But now I want to allow all users to try the full capability of the app for 7 days, then if they don't buy it, it reverts to limited capability.

I have now changed it to a 7 day trial in the store because that is the only way I can think of to determine how many days since the user first installed the app. So what I want to do now is, when the app loads:

1. Check to see if the user purchased the add-on. If so, enable all features
2. If they haven't purchased the add on, check to see if the current date is past the expiration date of the trial. If not, enable all features. If it is, limit the features.

But I think I have no way to test this logic. I first got a license for my app over a year ago when it wasn't configured as a trial. So, when I examine the app license in code, I see this:
[image: Properties of Windows.Services.Store.StoreAppLicense]

So, my questions are:

Is the Expiration date so far into the future because my app license didn't expire when I acquired it?

Is the IsTrial property false because of the same reason? When I acquired the license, it was not a trial license?

I really wish I had some way to reset my license so I could test it, instead of just coding it up and hoping it all works for my existing customers and my new customers. I was hoping I could create a local account on my computer  and test it that way, but that doesn't work either because the license is tied to the machine. If anyone can give me some ideas, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

David

Comment: per my understanding trial property can only be tested on a fresh new system which hasn't install your app before. So that's why you cannot test it. But I've saw some cases which said that IsTrial always false. Maybe I can help you test it. Can you share your app's name so that maybe I can download and test your app?

Comment: Thanks Barry. I appreciate the offer. I think I have worked out a solution. I am going to copy my Visual Studio solution, put it up in the store as a trial, but I won't make it discoverable.

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble to have to go through to make a new app and associate it with a new app in the store just so I can get a new license. I think Microsoft should come up with a solution like, let us create Developer User Accounts that we can user for testing, or let us clear our app license and add-on license status or something.

Comment: I have another case and in which the customer choose to create a VM to test this issue. In your case why not create a test app, then publish to store, then use a VM to as a new machine to test the result? It might be eaiser for you to test like this.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT, thanks for the suggestion. I finally had some time to work on this. I installed Virtual Box VM and installed a new Windows 10 ISO created from the Windows Media Creation tool onto the new VM. I created a local Windows login. Then I installed Visual Studio Community onto the VM. I then cloned my App repository in the VM. I associated the app with the store. I did actually log into Visual Studio with my developer email.

When debugging  my app and checking the license state, it still shows that the license is active and the license is not a trial and expire in 9999.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT, I would have thought that in the VM, the OS would have a different hardware ID and it would have issued a new license. What exactly is the app license associated with? It seems like it is not associated with the Machine Hardware ID. I thought that was the point of doing this in a VM. Is it doing this because I logged into Visual Studio? I guess I will have to create a new app in the store and test my trial code in the new app. Thanks,

Comment: what's the result if you directly see the result from your VM's store? Please see this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c2389bc-3c39-4b19-8b36-00d6bb018cb7/windowsservicesstore-trialtimeremaining-property-is-not-correct) in which Scott can get the right result out. I checked your original image and it looks like istrial is false. Maybe your app is still full license mode?

Comment: Its really worrying that MSFT has not given a solution for this yet?   is this deliberate?.  Its such a pain to do testing.